# What can I do to address mouse cursor vanishing under Linux Mint 21.2 ("Victoria")?

Tags: linux, drivers, mouse, linux-mint, xorg

I have a mouse cursor intermittently failing on me. My search did not find anything in questions here, but https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=377066 did seem to indicate the same problem, but without pointing out a solution that works on my computer.

The recommended solution was to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nouveau-swcursor.conf` with content:

```
#--makes mouse cursor re-appear
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "AccelMethod" "uxa"
    Option      "SWCursor"    "on"
EndSection
#--
```

I changed the `Driver` to `"i915"` after running `inxi -Gx`:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: Mitac
    driver: i915 v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)
    v: 4.5 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
```

However, this does not appear to have resolved the disappearing mouse cursor.

How can I request that the mouse cursor not disappear randomly, or perhaps not disappear at all?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you try a different mouse?  This will help determine if the issue is a Mint issue or a compatibility issue.

Comment: @John I was accidentally misleading. It's the computer's trackpad. I'll look to see if I can borrow a mouse to narrow things down.

Comment: @John It is the computer trackpad rather than a regular mouse. Using a regular mouse worked perfectly.

Comment: You need to make sure "solutions" you read are applicable to your system. The one from Mint forums obviously isn't. It's for Nvidia graphics that you don't have and running with the open-source alternative driver only. But you do have a problem with graphics (Intel), as shown by the `llvmpipe` output, that may or may not affect input devices.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you. I purchased a [Logitech M185 mouse](https://amzn.to/3TbZkrO), and it is showing the same kind of disappearing cursor issue behavior as the computer's trackpad.

Comment: As expected. Again, the problem seems to stem from the lack of graphics drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you. Are graphic drivers available (the system has a 7th generation i7 with a Geforce GTX driver)? Thanks,

Comment: The specs in your question don't show any Nvidia, only the Intel iGPU and that's the one with a problem.